# TCL extensions that depends on each other

Tags: c, linux, linker, dependencies, tcl

My question is a little bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168979/static-and-dynamic-library-linking) but it is about TCL extensions.

I am using C on Linux (gcc) and I have a package with three modules A, B, and C. Module A contains functions and also define (not only declare) global variables. I compile and link module A into a dynamic library (libA.so).

Now, I want that B and C are TCL extensions. Both are using functions and global variables from A, while C is also using functions from B. I have made B and C shared library (B.so and C.so) but without using "-Wl -soname". I made B.so depends on A.so, while C.so is without user dependencies. Although this is strange, bot extensions loaded and worked properly. Here is, what I have (A=libbiddy.so, B=bddscout.so, C=bddscoutIFIP.so):

```
meolic@meolic:/usr/lib/bddscout$ ldd *.so
bddscout.so:
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00177000)
    libbiddy.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbiddy.so.1 (0x00eca000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x00342000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0061f000)
bddscoutIFIP.so:
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00fc2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x00110000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00c75000)

meolic@meolic:/usr/lib/bddscout$ wish
% puts $tcl_patchLevel
8.5.8
% load ./bddscout.so
% load ./bddscoutIFIP.so
% info loaded
{./bddscoutIFIP.so Bddscoutifip} {./bddscout.so Bddscout} {{} Tk}
```

The problem is, that exactly the same package is not working everywhere. On a new computer extension C.so does not load.

```
meolic@altair:/usr/lib/bddscout$ ldd *.so
bddscout.so:
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76ef000)
    libbiddy.so.1 => /usr/lib/libbiddy.so.1 (0xb76c9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb754d000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f0000)
bddscoutIFIP.so:
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7780000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb75e8000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7781000)

meolic@altair:/usr/lib/bddscout$ wish
% puts $tcl_patchLevel
8.5.10
% load ./bddscout.so
% load ./bddscoutIFIP.so
couldn't load file "./bddscoutIFIP.so": ./bddscoutIFIP.so: undefined symbol: biddy_termFalse
```

The reported undefined symbol is one of global variables from A. Question1: is my approach correct as it works on some systems? Question2: why it does not work on a new system?

Comment: +1: Good question on a complex topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tcl's `load` command uses `dlopen()` under the covers (on Linux; it's different on other platforms of course) and it uses it with the `RTLD_LOCAL` flag; symbols in the library are *not* exported to the rest of the application. Because of this, unbound symbols in one dynamically-loaded library will not resolve against another one; this boosts isolation, but forces you to do more work to make things all function correctly where you want such a dependency to actually exist.

Your options are:

1. If `libscoutIFIP.so` depends on `libbiddy.so`'s symbols, tell this to the linker when building the library and the dynamic linker engine will sort it all out so that the dependency doesn't get loaded multiple times. That is, if a library depends on a symbol in another library, it should explicitly list that library as a dependency.
2. Arrange for `libbiddy.so` to export its symbols as a stub table (i.e., structure of pointers to functions/variables) through Tcl's package API (`Tcl_PkgProvide()`). Then when `libscoutIFIP.so` does `Tcl_PkgRequireEx()` on the `biddy` package, it will get a pointer to that stub table and can use the references within it instead of doing direct linking. This is how Tcl's stub mechanism works, and its awesome *and* portable *and* lets you do fairly complex API version management (if necessary). It's a bit more work to set up though. The [Tcler's Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3358) goes into quite a lot more depth on this topic.

If option 1 works for you, go with that; for Linux-specific code that should be just fine as the system dynamic linker isn't desperately dense (unlike the situation on Windows).

---

[EDIT]: Note that older versions of Tcl (up to 8.5.9) used `RTLD_GLOBAL` instead. It seems that this change should have been labelled `***POTENTIAL INCOMPATIBILITY***` in the release notes and trailed more widely. Apologies on behalf of the Tcl developers.

Comment: +1 on Tcl's stubs being awesome. Especially when comparing to Pythons offerings in that area (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/).

Comment: You didn't explain why the same package works on the system with tcl 8.5.8 and doesn't work on the system with tcl 8.5.10. Did 8.5.8 use `RTLD_GLOBAL` when loading extensions?

Comment: @Employed: Yes, due to [Bug #3216070](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3216070&group_id=10894&atid=110894). The summary of the [discussion](https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27211924) related to that bug is that no choice is perfect — if there was a single right choice, we'd go with that — but RTLD_LOCAL keeps the imperfections more localized. Sorry the change caused you problems.

Comment: Thanks. Just a final comment. Module A is used in other non-TCL projects, too (thus it must be a library). Modules B and C are TCL extensions, only (there is no point of creating system libraries). Moreover, C is an extension of B and this was the main problem. It was not trivial, but now, I can solve this in two different ways. 1ST VERSION: modules B and C are both dynamicaly linked with A, while B also exports its symbols as a stub table. 2ND VERSION: module B is statically linked with A (to avoid dependency on A) and export its symbols as a stub table, while C is dynamically linked with B.